# AutoFilter to delete data begin with multiple certain value

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have created a PowerQuery Report. And I need to export 3 different excel files every week and save them in the same folder, and the data columns positions are different in these 3 weekly files. After I export the data, I also need to delete the lines based on the cell value of a column. I'm doing it by putting a filter in that column to hide the lines with cell value begin with "VR", "VP", "LR" & "LP" (The lines begin with "VR", "VP", "LR" & "LP" are the lines I need to keep). Then delete all the visible lines.

I'm writing a VBA code to delete those lines. Below is my code but it didn't filter anything when I run the code.
Can someone please give me somoe suggestion to make it work? Many thanks

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("<>VR*", "<>VP*", "<>LR*", "<>LP*"), Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Is it xlor you should use?

Comment: `AutoFilter` only supports a maximum of two criteria with wild characters. It won't work with an array if you use the operator(`<>`). What kind of workaround to use will depend on what you're planning to do with the filtered range, probably the simplest being, if you want to delete rows. Add more detail and code to receive a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative by using loop. But it would be great if someone can tell me if it's possible to do it with autofilter

```
Sub delete()

Dim a As Long

For a = Sheet3.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1

If Left(Sheet3.Cells(a, "D").Value, 2) = "VR" Then
ElseIf Left(Sheet3.Cells(a, "D").Value, 2) = "LR" Then
ElseIf Left(Sheet3.Cells(a, "D").Value, 2) = "VP" Then
ElseIf Left(Sheet3.Cells(a, "D").Value, 2) = "LP" Then
Else
Rows(a).delete
End If

Next a

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a helper column plus a list of the values to be excluded:

[image]

The formula for your helper column:
`=COUNTIF(configExclude[exclude type],$B2)`

Using a separate list for the types to be excluded makes the solution easier to adjust - in case your boss wants you to exlcude more or less types :-)

Your `Autofilter`-code will then check the helper column for 0-values.